# Getting Started using ASP.NET Boilerplate with a clean development environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

I came across ASP.NET Boilerplate http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/ and want to get started using it to build a web-app.  I am not a web developer: my day job is a software dev but I deal mostly in ActiveX/COM with some Javascript html and python.

I tried downloading a template and launching it with Visual Studio 2013 Express. I know I'm missing something.

After installing the package and opening the file FirstWebAppCoreModule.cs, I get errors like

> The Type or Namespace Abp could not be found.

My question boils down to what are the steps I need to take to set up a development environment on a PC that has never been used for web dev.  Sorry for any ignorance of basic concepts if I'm missing something easy..

Comment: Have you built it? If it's using nuget then it will not download the ref dlls until you build it.

Comment: Best to start here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 2):

I'm the author of the ASP.NET Boilerplate.

Try "Enable nuget package restore" (Right click to the solution). But even if you success to run the app, ABP is not something that is easy for a non-web developer. It's a tool that makes you fast if you have knowlegde on web dev and some best practices.

Comment: Could you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46162053/asp-net-boilerplate-domain-layer-appears-to-contain-non-domain-classes ? I am trying to decide whether or not to use Boilerplate in a new DDD app. I cannot find any guidance explaining when it should and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing this issue but I have resolved this as abp requires dotnet framwork  .NET Framework 4.5.2 but previously it was  .NET Framework 4.5.1.
So download the latest  .NET Framework 4.5.2 developer kit from microsoft site install this in your machine.
Now open visual studio with abp solution and try to change the target framework of solution with latest  .NET Framework 4.5.2 by right click on the project select properties and in application select target framework  .NET Framework 4.5.2 from dropdown repeat this in each prject and change target framwork and now build your solution.
Error will be resolved and will build with 0 Error