# ASP.NET Boilerplate Domain Layer appears to contain non-Domain classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate

I have recently done some analysis of ASP.Net Boilerplate (https://aspnetboilerplate.com). I have noticed that the domain layer (MyProject.Core) has folders for the following (these are created by default):

```
    Authorization
    Confirguration
    Editions
    Features
    Identity
    Localization
    MultiTenancy
    etc
```

Why would you put all of this in the Domain Layer of an application? From what I can see; I believe most of this code should be found in the Application Layer (which could also be the service layer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question, if you just look at the folder names. But I suppose you haven't investigated the source code in the folders much.

First of all, I don't say it's the best solution architecture. We are constantly improving it and we may have faults. Notice that our approach is a mix of best practices & pragmatic approach. I will try to explain it briefly.

You are talking about this project: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/tree/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core So, let's investigate the folders:

#### Localization

It does not include any localization logic (it's done in framework level, in ABP. Thus, it's in infrastructure layer). It just defines localization texts.

While normally it can be easily moved to web layer (no direct dependency in Core project), we put it in the Core layer since we think it may be needed in another application too. Think that you have a Windows Service has only Reference to the .Core project and want to use localization texts, say to send email to a user in his own language. Notice that Windows Service should not have a reference to Web layer normally. So, we have a pragmatic approach here. We could add localization to another dll project, but that would make the solution more complicated.

#### Authorization

Mainly includes User, Role.. entities and UserManager and RoleManager domain classes. Similar to localization, it does not include actual authorization logic. It also includes some other classes but they do not make much. We thought putting these here would help us if we have more application layers. As you know every application can have it's own application layer as a best practice.

#### Confirguration

AppConfigurations is here to share 'configuration reading' code between different apps (Migrator and Web app). Again, this could be inside another "Shared Utils" library. But we wanted to keep solution structure balanced, so it reflects major layer and structures yet is not so complicated for intermediate level developers.

#### Editions

Just includes EditionManager class which is a domain service for Edition management.

#### Features

Just includes FeatureValueStore which is a repository-like adapter class. See it's code, it's already empty.

#### MultiTenancy

Includes Tenant entity and TenantManager class which are already parts of domain layer. Again, nothing here includes infrastructure-related multi-tenancy features (like data filtering or determining current tenant).

... and so on...

So, do not just see names and have idea, please check the project deeper. Some code can be moved to upper layers or an utils library, but I think general structure is good to start a DDD architected application.

Answer (score 1):

What you see it is called [Module Zero](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Overall), it aims to implements all fundamental concepts of ASP.NET Boilerplate framework such as tenant management (multi-tenancy), role management, user management, session, authorization (permission management), setting management, language management, audit logging and so on.

Module-Zero defines entities and implements domain logic (domain layer) because it is part of the `configuration context` of your system.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you provide an example of domain logic that it executes? +1 for the reference to Module Zero.